# jquery check if string starts with and then extract it

Tags: jquery, split, dynamic-data

I seem to have figured out how to do #1, but, not sure how to do the second part...

I have various p elements, each with a series of classes:

```
<p class="note cxid-45 contextual-item">Example</p>
```

I'm trying to determine if:

(1) the class list contains a class beginning with "cxid-"
(2) if it does, I'd like to store the full class name

So, in the above markup, I'd like to store "cxid-45" in a variable: c

I managed this:

```
var pcl = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");

if(pcl.indexOf('cxid-') >= 0) {
  alert('found');  
  //This works, but not sure how to get the full string into the variable
  var c = ???;
} else {
  alert('not found');
  var c = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var el=$('p[class*="cxid-"]');
var c=el.length ? el.prop('class').match(/cxid-[^\s]+/g)[0] : 'Not Found!';
alert(c); // If found then it'll alert the class name, otherwise 'Not Found!'
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/PNzJ7/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
var c = $(this).attr("class").match(/cxid-[^\s]+/g);
```

`c` will be an `array` of classes, which start with `'cxid-'`

```
if( c.length > 0 ){
    alert("There is at least on class,which starts with 'cxid-'");
}else{
    alert("Nothing found");
}
```